# Execute process and find lines in its output

Tags: powershell

How can I execute a process and find lines in its output that contain a certain search text? I need to find two different patterns, first one, and if it's not there another, and then use a value from the same line.

I tried to execute a process like this:

```
$lines = (youtube-dl --list-formats $url) |out-string
```

The command prints something like this:

```
[youtube] 5qap5aO4i9A: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 5qap5aO4i9A: Downloading m3u8 information
[youtube] 5qap5aO4i9A: Downloading MPD manifest
[info] Available formats for 5qap5aO4i9A:
format code  extension  resolution note
91           mp4        256x144     290k , avc1.42c00b, 15.0fps, mp4a.40.5
92           mp4        426x240     546k , avc1.4d4015, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.5
93           mp4        640x360    1209k , avc1.4d401e, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.2
94           mp4        854x480    1568k , avc1.4d401f, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.2
95           mp4        1280x720   2969k , avc1.4d401f, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.2
96           mp4        1920x1080  5420k , avc1.640028, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.2 (best)
```

I don't know what that is, a single multi-line string or an array of lines, I can't find that out. But none of these often cited methods work: I either get nothing or all the lines at once.

```
$lines |where { $_ -like "*1280x720*" }
$lines |where { $_ -like "1280x720" }
@($lines) -match "1280x720"
```

I'm looking for "1280x720" and as fallback "(best)".

In the matching line, if it exists, I need only the first number of that line. In this case that would be "95" or "96". How does that work with PowerShell? I could easily do it in Bash and know that CMD is unable to help me.

(All of the shown code here is gathered from the web. I will never understand the PowerShell syntax, I'll happily stick with C# and Bash; PowerShell is incomprehensible to my mind. Getting something to work in PS takes longer than writing a C program for it.)

Comment: this >>> ` | out-string` <<< converts your array of strings into ONE multiline string. that means that any match will give you _the entire multiline string_ ... but you likely want only the single matching string. so, leave off the ` | out-string` and do as ReddyLutonadio shows instead. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```ps
youtube-dl --list-formats $url | Select-String "1280x720"
```

I am using the [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2) cmdlet as it:

> uses regular expression matching to search for text patterns in input strings and files. You can use Select-String similar to grep in UNIX or findstr.exe in Windows.

The output of youtbut-dl will be piped to Select-String which in turn will select the lines that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Drop `| Out-String` and loop through the array of lines using `switch` to match on both `1280x720` or `best`:

```
$lines = (youtube-dl --list-formats $url)
switch -Regex ($lines) {
    '1280x720|best' { 
        # return the number in the first column
        ($_ -split '\s+')[0]
    }
}
```

Using your example lines, this will return

```
95
96
```